# Assume W is a subspace of a vector space V and that $T:V \rightarrow V$ is linear. Suppose that $V=R(T) \oplus W$ and W is T-invariant.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> assume W is a subspace of a vector space V and that $T:V \rightarrow V$ is linear. Suppose that $V=R(T) \oplus W$ and W is T-invariant.

a).prove $W \subseteq N(T)$

proof:

Since it is T-invariant, $T(W) \subseteq W$ 
Since $R(T) \bigcap W=0$, that means $R(T) \bigcap T(W)=0$

Since $T(V)=R(T)$, $R(T) \bigcap T(W)=0$

$T(V) \bigcap T(W)=T(W)=0$,

then for any $x \in W, T(x)=0 \in N(W) \subseteq N(T)$
Hence proved.

I am wondering for this one if there's a much simpler way to prove it.

b).Show if V is finite-dimensional,then W=N(T)

For this one, it seems obvious, by dimension theorem,

$dim(V)=dim(N(T))+dim(R(T))$
Since $V=R(T)+W$, we can conclude that $dim(V)=dim(R(T))+dim(W)$
But it mentioned V is finite-dimensional, what theorem/definition should I use to conclude this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\;w\in W,$ where $W$ is a $T$-invariant subspace of $V.$ Then, for any vector in the range $r\in R(T),$ we have that $w=v-r,$ where $v\in V.$ Thus,

$$W\stackrel{\text{invariant!}}\ni Tw=T(v-r)\in R(T)\implies Tw\in R(T)\cap W=0\implies w\in N(T)$$

shows that $W \subseteq N(T),$ as desired.

Comment: I don't get why w=v-r? Why can we assume this is true?

Comment: @Beacon Because $$\;V=R(T)\oplus W\implies \forall\,v\in V\;\exists!\,r\in R(T),\,w\in W\;\;s.t.\;\;v=r+w\ldots$$